# How to store a pair of strings in a non-unique list

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a situation where I am loading some config data from an XML document and I have a bunch of elements that contain pairs of strings. I am tryign to look for a good way of storing these in a single object.

I'm after something like `Dictionary<string,string>` except that I want to be able to have duplicate keys and I will never be searching it for a single value, jsut iterating through it to generate some HTML to put on a page.

Is there a good object to use? I know I could create a little class of my own to hold the two bits of data and have a List of them but that seems a bit excessive.

I could also just have two Lists and just know that the nth element in one goes with the nth element in the other. This strikes me as a recipe for disaster of some kind though.

There is also System.Web.UI.Pair that seems to do what I want but I'm not sure if its good practice to use that given its in the System.Web.UI namespace...

I'm probably missing something obvious but I thought I'd ask rather than spending any more of my time trying to think about the best way to do this. :)

Comment: You can use List < List < string > >

Comment: Would KeyValuePair suit your application? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx

Comment: Since it's not unique, so why don't you use `List<string[]>`?

Comment: The reason I am not keen on List<List<string>> and List<string[]> is because I feel that I would like more constraint on the inner part. I want to know that there is no way that the inner object can have more than the two values that I expect in it. I think this is why I like the Tuple suggestion. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would go over creating a little class of my own to hold the two bits of data and have a List of them, that seems quite right to me.

Probably you will end adding some logic there sooner or latter.

Comment: In this case I would be fairly confident in not wanting to add logic there. It is purely a data construct to be used as an inbetween phase from XML and the main logic. You do make a good point though for the case when there is potential for expansion.

Comment: Accepted this answer in the end because of the excellent point you made in comment to the other answer of getting much more sensible names if I make my own small class.

Comment: Thanks! Personally I always have maintenance in mind when I code. The easier code to read the better.

Comment: I see a lot of people recommending Tuples for this but I consider that to be lazy/sloppy development. Not withstanding the changes Microsoft has recently made (field naming etc) I think that Tuples are an abomination and that a simple POCO/DTO is the way to go everytime.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` or a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`.

You would add items like this:

```
// for List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(value1, value2));

// for List<Tuple<string, string>>
list.Add(Tuple.Create(value1, value2));
```

You can access the items like this:

```
foreach(var item in list)
{
    // for List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    var value1 = item.Key;
    var value2 = item.Value;

    // for List<Tuple<string, string>>
    var value1 = item.Item1;
    var value2 = item.Item2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about being able to create KeyValuePair objects manually. And I think Tuple is probably what I am most after. KeyValuePair has the implication of one being a lookup for the other which is not the case here. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway think that creating your own simple class will provide better maintainability of your code because you will have better property names than "Item1" and "Item2". I think it's worth the small effort.

Comment: @SoMoS: that is an excellent point. Especially since I've now realised that I can't use Tuple (because I'm not using .NET4 I assume).

Comment: @Chris: Yes, Tuple has been introduced in .NET 4.

Comment: Why not use NameValueCollection?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `NameValueCollection` class.

Comment: Why would you suggest that? Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: @TZHX: Because it is an existing .NET class and its purpose is exactly to store pairs of strings and it allows duplicate keys, i.e. non-unique. It looks easier and nicer than `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` or `List<Tuple<string,string>>`. I prefer to not reinvent the wheel and create new class with the same functionality.

Comment: One downside is that this implements `ICollection<>`, but not `IList<>`, despite having `IList<>`-like methods, such as `Add()`/`Remove()`/`Clear()`

Comment: @micodemus13: `NameValueCollection` implements all of these: `Add`, `Remove`, `Clear` and `Count`.